# How to read a custom type from AppSettings in .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, appsettings

Here is my AppSettings:

```
   "Simulation": {
        "ApiUrl": "YourApiUrl",
        "Groups": {
            "Group": {
                "Name": "YourGroup",
                "Latitude": 45.50884,
                "Longitude": -73.58781,
                "Radius": 500
            }
        },
        "Planifications": {
            "Planification": {
                "GroupName": "YourGroup",
                "At": "23:50",
                "Status": 10,
                "DatePlannedStart": "2019-07-29 15:51:49.1948310 +00:00",
                "DatePlannedEnd": "2019-07-29 15:51:49.1948310 +00:00",
                "DateReplannedStart": "",
                "DateReplannedEnd": ""
            }
        }
    }
```

In *Simulation / Notification [0] / At* there is a property "At" with a time value (23:50).

Here is class for the settings

```
    public class SimulationSettings
    {
        public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

        public Group[] Groups { get; set; }
        public Planification[] Planifications { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public int Radius { get; set; }
    }

    public class Planification
    {
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public Time At { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Time
    {
        //TODO
    }
```

How can I get the value "23:50" from the AppSettings and set my object? Which Interfaces my class Time need to implement?

Thanks for your help :_)

Comment: Is there a reason your `At` property can't be a `TimeSpan` object? That should deserialize the config the way you want.

Comment: That's a good question! In my case, you gave the good answer. But I m still curious to know how to do with another custom type?